# MongoDB drop duplicates with ensureIndex but keep the last entry not the first

Tags: mongodb, duplicates

I have a duplicate problem.

I'm trying to delete all duplicates from a MongoDB collection, the problem is I don't want to keep the first entry but the last one.

This is how I keep the first entry:

`db.CUDB.ensureIndex( { CUid: 1 }, { unique: true, dropDups: true } )`

But I would like to be able to insureIndex in a reverse manner and keep the last added entry instead of the first.

What is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ensureIndex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/) does not provide a way to do this. Also it is not telling which values will be deleted.

In your case I would try to do the following (which will surely be slower then ensure index).
I also assume that you have some field (in my case `created_at`) based on what you decide whether one document is older then another):

```
var checked = {}; // basically a hash, which ensures O(1) lookup
db.coll.find().sort({created_at: -1}).forEach(function(o){
  if (o['CUid'] in checked){
    db.coll.remove({_id: o['_id']});
  } else {
    checked[o['CUid']] = 1;
  }
})
```

So basically we iterate all your documents in reversed order (newest the first) and check whether we already have seen your `CUid` field. If we have not, then leave this document as is and mark it as seen. If later we see any other document with the same `CUid`, we can remove it.

You will end up with one full scan of your collection and `N` additional db calls for every duplicated element.

Reverse sorting will ensure that the newest element will be saved.

**P.S.**

> Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not
>   tried it.

and tell me how it goes.

**P.P.S.** if you still can not sort all the collections in mongo, I would try to do this on application layer. Basically you find all your collections, sort them with whatever language you want and then do the same logic there as well.

Comment: That looks awesome but I have a small memory issue: `Runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33578371 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes` Also, the db has ~300k entries and is around 1.6GB :-s

Comment: @Eek this is a big issue :-). It means that there is not enough memory to sort all your collection. What might help is to create an index on your analogue of `created_at`, because without index you can not use more then 64MB (what surprising for me is that in your case it shuts down after 32MB)